# How many remotes can LIRC support on RPi?

Tags: pi-3, lirc

I have LIRC setup on my RPi3 to includes a few remotes that correspond to different TVs in my house. I loop over the remotes to send multiple `ir_send ...` commands and that way all my devices work.

I want to share this with multiple friends and for that reason would need to load many many remote configs. Is there a limit to how many different remote confs LIRC can load on the Pi?